# How to cast UIElement to Rectangle

Tags: c#

I have some rectangles stored in Canvas.Children, and when traversing the Canvas.Children, I can use

```
for (int i=0; i<Canvas.Children.Count; i++)
{
     UIElement ui = Canvas.Children[i];
}
```

However I don't know how to convert ui into System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle. Could someone help?

Comment: Rectangle rect = Canvas.Children[i] as Rectangle;

Comment: I'd advise you to learn about casting in c#

Comment: @LuisFilipe, thank you! I'm a newcomer to C#

Answer (score 0):

A useful answer can be found in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935482/how-to-change-a-value-of-uielement).

Also a useful guide to casting can be found on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(ui is Rectangle)
{
Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)ui;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is based on earlier responses. It might be useful for hit boxes, as in  `collision=hitBox.IntersectsWith(rectList[rcount]);`.

```
Rect[] rectList;
int rcount = 0; 
for (int i=0;i < CanvasB.Children.Count; i++) {
  UIElement ui = CanvasB.Children[i];
  if (ui is Rectangle) {
    rectList[rcount] = new Rect(
      Canvas.GetLeft(ui), 
      Canvas.GetTop(ui), (double)ui.GetValue(ActualWidthProperty), 
      (double)ui.GetValue(ActualHeightProperty)
    );
    rcount++;
  }
}
```